# Choice combination, which type of analyses?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data

I've datas as follows:

```
           data=structure(list(Id = c(2L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 31L, 33L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 
82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 
95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 117L, 
118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 
141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 
152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 
163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 
197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 
219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 
230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 237L, 238L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 
243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 
254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 
265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 
276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 287L, 
289L, 291L), `5` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `3` = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 
1, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 
1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `1` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 
0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 
0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0.5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), `2` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `4` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), D = c(1, 
0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0.5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 
1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), B = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), A = c(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), E = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Id", "5", "3", 
"1", "2", "4", "D", "B", "A", "E", "C"), row.names = c(NA, 250L
), class = "data.frame")
```

for `Id` represent a customer. There is two products, the first product is represented by its few versions `1,2,3,4,5` and the product 2 is represented by versions `A,B,C,D`.

A customer will buy the two types of products. He can also buy one or few versions of the same product. For example for the first product, he can buy version 1 and 3, and the second version A and B.

As you see in my datas, I ponderate the sum in order to have for sum(product1)=1 and sum(product2)=1.

I want to study the combinaison between choices between the two products (`1,2,3,4,5`) and (`A,B,C,D`) in the other side.

The typr of question that I'm trying to investigate, for example : Are poeple that take version 1 and 3 are more likely to take the version D of the other product ?

How to do this statistically ? because there is combinaison in the same product that complicate the analyses ?

Thanks you a lot !

EDIT 2 : I've used table before extracted information seperately and ponderate them :

```
         A A,B A,D A,E   B   C   D   E
  1      23   0   9   1  11   7  82   2
  1,2     4   0   0   0   0   0  10   0
  1,2,3   0   0   1   0   2   1   0   0
  1,3     3   0   9   0   2   0  25   3
  2       2   1   0   0   2   1  18   1
  2,3     1   0   0   0   0   0   6   0
  3      19   0  13   0  19  11 172   5
  4       0   0   0   0   1   2   9   1
  5       1   0   1   0   0   1   9   1
```

EDIT 3 :my original datas was, do you think that I should work with instead and do you have an idea which type of analyses suits this type of datas ?

```
    data=structure(list(Id = c(2L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 31L, 33L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 
82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 
95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 117L, 
118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 
141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 
152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 
163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 
197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 
219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 
230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 237L, 238L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 
243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 
254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 
265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 
276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 287L, 
289L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 
301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 
313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 
324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 
338L, 339L, 340L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 
350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 
361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 
372L, 373L, 374L, 376L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 
384L, 385L, 386L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 395L, 396L, 
397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 
408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 
419L, 420L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 429L, 430L, 
431L, 432L, 433L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 442L, 
443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 
454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 
465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 475L, 
476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 486L, 
487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 
498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 
509L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 519L, 
520L, 521L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 531L, 
532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 541L, 542L, 543L, 
544L, 545L), Product1 = c("5", "3", "1", "3", "3", "5", "1,3", 
"3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "1,3", "3", "3", "1,3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "2,3", "3", "3", "3", "5", "1,3", "3", "5", 
"1,3", "3", "1,2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"4", "3", "1,3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1,3", "3", "3", "1,3", 
"1", "3", "1,3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "1", "3", 
"3", "5", "3", "3", "5", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", 
"1", "3", "3", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"1,3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "1", "4", "4", "3", "5", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "2", "1,3", "3", 
"1", "1,3", "1", "1", "3", "3", "1", "3", "1", "2,3", "3", "4", 
"4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "3", "1", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "4", 
"1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1,3", "3", "1,3", "4", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1,3", "1", "1", 
"1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1,3", "1", "3", "1", "3", "1", "3", 
"1", "3", "3", "1", "3", "1", "3", "1,2,3", "2,3", "5", "1", 
"3", "3", "1", "3", "1", "5", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "3", 
"3", "1,3", "3", "1", "2,3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1,3", 
"3", "1", "3", "4", "3", "1", "1", "1", "5", "3", "1", "1", "1", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "1,2", "3", "1", "1", "1,3", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "3", "1,3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"4", "1", "1", "3", "1,3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1,3", 
"3", "1", "1,3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "1,3", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "3", "3", "3", "5", "1", "1,2", "1", "1", "2", "3", 
"2", "1,3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1,3", "3", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "1", "3", "2", "2,3", "4", "1", "1", "3", "1", "3", 
"1,2", "2", "1,3", "1", "3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "1,2", "1", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1,3", "1", "3", "1", "3", "4", 
"3", "1,3", "1,2", "3", "3", "1", "3", "1", "1,3", "3", "1", 
"1,3", "1", "5", "3", "3", "2", "1,3", "3", "1,3", "3", "3", 
"1,2", "3", "1,3", "3", "3", "1", "1,2", "1,2", "3", "2", "1,2,3", 
"1", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "5", "3", "1,2,3", "3", "3", 
"3", "1", "1,2", "3", "1", "3", "3", "1,3", "1,3", "2", "3", 
"3", "1", "3", "1,2", "2", "2,3", "2", "3", "1,3", "2", "3", 
"3", "1", "1", "3", "1,3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "2,3", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "3", "3", "1", "4", "3", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"3", "3", "1,3", "1,3", "2", "1,2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "3", 
"1,2", "1,3", "3", "1,2", "1", "3", "3", "2", "1", "3", "3", 
"1", "3", "1,3", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "1,2,3", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1"), Product2 = c("D", "B", 
"A,D", "A,D", "A,D", "A,D", "A,D", "D", "D", "A", "A,D", "A,D", 
"E", "A,D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A,D", "A", "D", "D", "A", 
"D", "D", "D", "A", "A,D", "A", "D", "D", "A", "A", "D", "D", 
"D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A,D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "A", "D", "A,D", "A,D", "D", "D", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "A", "D", "D", 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "B", "B", "D", "A,D", 
"D", "A,D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "B", "A,D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "A,D", "D", 
"D", "A", "D", "A", "A,E", "A", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", 
"D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A,D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "B", 
"B", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "A", "D", "D", "C", "D", "E", "B", 
"A,D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", 
"A", "D", "B", "D", "D", "A,D", "A,D", "D", "C", "D", "A", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A,D", "C", 
"A", "D", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "A,D", "B", 
"B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A,D", "D", "D", "A", "A", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "D", "C", "D", "C", "D", "A", "D", 
"D", "D", "B", "D", "D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D", "B", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "A", "D", "A,D", "A,D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", 
"D", "E", "D", "B", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "C", "D", "C", "D", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "E", 
"D", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A,D", "D", 
"E", "D", "A,D", "A,D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A,D", 
"D", "D", "E", "A", "D", "E", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "B", 
"A", "D", "D", "D", "C", "A", "E", "D", "A,B", "D", "E", "A", 
"D", "A", "D", "C", "E", "A,D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "C", "D", "C", 
"D", "A,D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D", "A,D", "A", "C", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "C")), .Names = c("Id", "Product1", 
"Product2"), row.names = c(2L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 31L, 33L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 
54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 117L, 
118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 
141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 
152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 
163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 
197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 
219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 
230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 237L, 238L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 
243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 
254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 
265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 
276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 287L, 
289L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 
301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 
313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 
324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 
338L, 339L, 340L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 
350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 
361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 
372L, 373L, 374L, 376L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 
384L, 385L, 386L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 395L, 396L, 
397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 
408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 
419L, 420L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 429L, 430L, 
431L, 432L, 433L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 442L, 
443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 
454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 
465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 475L, 
476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 486L, 
487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 
498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 
509L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 519L, 
520L, 521L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 531L, 
532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 541L, 542L, 543L, 
544L, 545L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

I derive that you don't yet know *which* relations to analyse. You could for example use some clustering to identify relations worth investigating further:

```
> # remove constants
> data <- data.frame(data[,-which(apply(data, 2, sd)==0)], check.names = T)

> # clusters 
> k <- kmeans(x = data[,-1], centers = 3, iter.max = 10000) # you likely need more than 3 clusters
> table(k$cluster)

 1  2  3 
17  9  4 

> k$center

          X5        X3        X1         D   B         A         E   C
1 0.05882353 0.9411765 0.0000000 0.8529412 0.0 0.1470588 0.0000000 0.0
2 0.11111111 0.5000000 0.3888889 0.1666667 0.0 0.7222222 0.1111111 0.0
3 0.00000000 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5

# visualize cluster centers
> library(lattice)
> levelplot(t(k$center), col.regions=gray(100:0/100), ylab='cluster nr.')
```

[image: Cluster centers visualization]

Those clusters give you an idea of what some trends worth looking at might be. You could use those to split your data into more homogeneous groups, which you can then analyse/model further:

```
> # look at samples of one example cluster (nr. 1: people that buy 3 seem to buy D and/or A)
> table(data[data$X3 > 0.9,][,c('D', 'A')])

     A
D      0 0.5  1
  0    4   0  3
  0.5  0   5  0
  1   11   0  0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, # remove constants because 2 and 4 = 0 ? it was just a dput(head(data,30)), so I've value in all column, I' should delete this line ? (please see the edit to see the complete data). Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I removed constants because they a) don't add information - so removing them doesn't hurt, and b) they cause problems with certain analysis (e.g. correlation). If they are actually constants in your data you should remove them too - otherwise just skip this step.

Comment: ok thanks, but I still have a problem. I expected to see dark cluster between D and 1 because through my cross tabulation "table()" i've value that indicate that there is strong relation between D and 3. Plese see EDIT 2. Thanks again!

Comment: In your example data, `D` and `3` are not very strongly correlated: `corrplot(cor(data[,c('D', '3')]))`, so getting clusters with that property is unlikely. Try varying the nr. of clusters: I could imagine you likely have more than 3 groups or clusters of buying behaviours for those 2 products.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the corrplot packages. Thanks. I've  492 customer for 2 products and each product 5 versions. The question is what is the perfect nb of cluster that I must choose, and why the plot of cluster changing for each run ?? Thanks again it is very interesting !

Comment: [Initialization with K-Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Initialization_methods) is usually random, therefore it converges differently each run. The order of clusters will be different too, hence the visualization looks different even when representing very similar clusters. As you don't have an error measure, automatically choosing a "best K" will be difficult - you might need to try out different K. You could also look into [other clustering methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis): some choose the nr. of clusters automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40774/discussion-between-ranell-and-geekoverdose).

Comment: I've added in the EDIT 3 the original datas. Still investigating about Clustering, but if you have any other idea about how to manipulate this type of informations I would be very greateful. If clustering seems yet the best option I'll try to understand more and more how it works. Thanks a lot!